# How to specify a directory for custom ohai plugins?

Tags: chef-infra, ohai-gem

The [ohai-example](https://github.com/coderanger/ohai-example) helps a lot to package a ohai plugin
in a cookbook. In my default recipe I use

```
 ohai_plugin 'ohai-example'
```

After a chef.run the custom ohai plugin is placed at

```
 /home/user/cookbooks/ohai/plugins/ohai-example.rb
```

I use the following parameters for the chef run:

```
chef-client --local-mode -c config.rb
```

My config.rb

```
chef_zero.enabled true
cookbook_path [
    '/home/user/.chef/cookbooks',    #ohai cookbook
    '/home/user/cookbooks'           #ohai-example cookbook 
]
local_mode true
```

Is it possible to specify another directory for the ohai plugins?

Answer (score 0):

use [`ohai_plugin` resource](https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/ohai#ohai_plugin) and utilize the `path` attribute

> `path` - The path to your custom plugin directory. Defaults to a directory named 'plugins' under the directory 'ohai' in the Chef config dir.

Comment: This is the path to your custom plugin directory. I would like to change the directory in which the plugins are copied by the ohai cookbook.